# How to read a middle size-specified chunk of a file in Python

Tags: python, io

If I have a text file, what is a clean way to start from a line at near the 5th MB into the file and read the subsequent 5 MB worth of lines into a list?  Ideally into a list of lines.

I know `f.seek(5000000)` starts at the 5th MB, and I can probably estimate the next 5MB if I estimate the number of lines, but would be nice if there is a more exact way.  Tried to play around with f.readlines, but that didn't work

Comment: Do you want `f.seek(5*1024*1024)` with `f.read(5*1024*1024)`?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify, I would like the lines, not a list of characters

Comment: You can read 5 MB worth of characters and then split them into lines.

Comment: Is there a quick/clean way?  Splitting `a = f.read(N)` will give a list of words, not a a list of lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior I'm assuming would be to seek 5 MBs into the file and split the next 5 MBs into lines. You'd want something like:

```
f.seek(5*1024*1024)
lines = f.read(5*1024*1024).splitlines()
```

Or manual counting (recommended method, much more efficient):

```
f.seek(5*1024*1024)
lines = []
while f.tell() < 10*1024*1024:
    line = f.readline(10*1024*1024-f.tell())
    lines.append(line)
```

However, remember to open the files in binary mode if you're counting bytes!

Comment: oh Python, gotta love it, didn't know about splitlines()

Comment: @db1234 Just note that `splitlines` will discard empty lines (usually wanted). If you don't want that, use `split('\n')` (`split` allows you to specify a delimiter).